# How to get the real data text, with already substring text?

Tags: java, android, listview, substring

I'm doing create an Catalogue Movie app. I have a ListView which contains an ImageView, title, description, and release date.

In the ListView, I take a substring of the description, because it's too long if showed in a ListView, and now I want to get the real description, in the DetailActivity (`setOnItemClickListener`).

This is my code:

```
try {
    String title = object.getString("title");
    String description = object.getString("overview");
    double movieRatet = object.getDouble("vote_average");
    String movieRate = new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(movieRatet);
    String releaseDate = object.getString("release_date");
    String posterUrl = object.getString("poster_path");
    posterUrl = POSTER_BASE_URL + "w185" + posterUrl;
    description = description.length() > 64 ? description.substring(0,64)+"...":description;

    Log.d("movie poster", posterUrl);
    Log.d("movie title ", title);
    Log.d("movie description ", description);
    Log.d("movie release ", releaseDate);

    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.rate = releaseDate;
    this.imgurl = posterUrl;


}catch (Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my `OnItemClickListener`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            RelativeLayout listItem = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_item);
            TextView clickedItemView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_judul);
            TextView clickedItemView2 = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_deskripsi);
            TextView clickedItemView3 = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_rate);
            String title = clickedItemView.getText().toString();
            String desk = clickedItemView2.getText().toString();
            String rate = clickedItemView3.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            desk.substring(0);
            i.putExtra("title", title);
            i.putExtra("desk", desk);
            i.putExtra("rate", rate);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

Picture of the DetailActivity:

[image: picture of detailactivity]

I want to get the full description, how?

Comment: pass all parameters to next activity.

Comment: Do you mean an expandable listview? Something like [this](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout)?

Comment: save all (original ) data in arraylist of modalclass and by clicked position get that particular object and pass that object to next activity

Comment: Yes you can pass the description in the intent then you can retrieve the description and can access the values.

Comment: can you example the code? @BapusahebShinde and ABHISHEK HONEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a params "fullMessage" to storage the all of the message,and "description" to storage some message.Then use i.putExtra("desk", fullMessage) to carry full message to another activity.

Another solution is to add those attribute to your TextView in ListView

```
 <TextView
 <!--  other value -->
 android:maxLines="3"
 android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

And you can put full message to this TextView,it will folding itself when the message is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not overwrite your description variable. Instead of above have one more variable that holds your truncated value, say overview.

```
String overview = description.length() > 64 ? description.substring(0,64)+"...":description;
```

Then your description variable will continue to hold the original value. Just use that where you need.

Comment: sorry sir i cant understand,i still need that substring code,for description on the listview layout

Comment: Yes right. So you need two variables. One variable, say description as in your code holds the original value. Another variable, overview (as i mentioned above) holds the truncated value. In your listview layout, use the overview variable to display the data while in your detailed view use description variable to show entire name. String is immutable in Java, so invoking substring on description field does not truncate it there. It stays as is.

Comment: okay got it now sir,but how to get the description variabel??,,in my mainactivity(the listview),i just do putExtra from the listview

Comment: Just like you are doing currently, no need to change that implementation. Just change the variable you are passing over. All you need to do is, just like your first sample code where you are storing this.description = etc. there you add an instance level variable to hold full description and overview. Then you pass over the field containing full value, to your next view as you are currently passing the truncated value. I can't say in terms of your classes as I do not know the names of your classes :).

Comment: Cool. Please accept the answer and close this, then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mymodalclass:make class

public class MyModal {

    String title ;
    String description ;
    double movieRatet ;
    String movieRate;
    String releaseDate;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getMovieRatet() {
        return movieRatet;
    }

    public void setMovieRatet(double movieRatet) {
        this.movieRatet = movieRatet;
    }

    public String getMovieRate() {
        return movieRate;
    }

    public void setMovieRate(String movieRate) {
        this.movieRate = movieRate;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getPosterUrl() {
        return posterUrl;
    }

    public void setPosterUrl(String posterUrl) {
        this.posterUrl = posterUrl;
    }

    String posterUrl ;
}
```

//****************************************

```
while parsing data :
```

Arraylist list = new ArrayList();

```
for(int i=0;i<yourjsonarray.length();i++){
JSONObject object = yourjsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
MyModal m = new MyModal();
m.setTitle(object.getString("title"));//like this set all data
//now add this object to list
list.add(m);

}




//now when you click list just get clicked position and by this position get that particular object and pass that to next activity
ex: position = your_clicked_position
MyModal clicked_modal_object = (MyModal) list.get(your_clicked_position);

//now pass this clicked_modal_object  to next activity
```

Comment: aww,,i didnt understand sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variables.(I'm sure this is what @Gautam mentioned) The first is the full description and the second is the shorter description.

```
  String description = object.getString("overview"); // full
  String shortDesc = description.length() > 64 ? description.substring(0,64)+"...":description; // add this to listView
  Log.d("movie description ", shortDesc);
```

---

> I want to get the real description, in the DetailActivity
>   (setOnItemClickListener)

When button clicked, get the description `string` instead

```
i.putExtra("desk", description);
```

**Note: Make sure you set description as globally.**